# Gulp 4 running in development mode

Tags: gulp-4, development-mode

I changed Gulp3 into Gulp4. In my gulpfile.js I created a task: if I am doing a modification, I can see it immediately in the development mode, without building my website:

```
gulp.task('serve-php', function () {
  connect.server({
      port: 9001,
      base: 'app',
      open: false
  });
  var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
  browserSync.init({
      notify: false,
      port  : 9000,
      server: {
          baseDir   : ['.tmp', 'app'],
          routes    : {
              '/node_modules': 'node_modules'

          },
          middleware: function (req, res, next) {
              var url = req.url;
              if (!url.match(/^\/(styles|fonts|node_modules)\//)) {
                  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:9001' });
              } else {
                  next();
              }
          }
      }
  });
  gulp.watch([
      'app/*.html',
      'app/*.php',
      'app/**/*.php',
      'app/**/**/*.php',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'app/images/**/*',
      '.tmp/fonts/**/*'
  ]).on('change', function() {
    browserSync.reload();
  });
  gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', gulp.series('styles'));
  gulp.watch('app/fonts/**/*', gulp.series('fonts'));
 });
```

But when I run `gulp serve-php`, my website doesn't have any css and js and I don't know how to tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

You aren’t seeing any of the compiled assets because `serve-php` doesn’t run the `styles` or `fonts` tasks. It is only watching the source files for changes. So won’t run them until changes are made.

The simplest solution is to create another task that compiles your frontend assets first and then spins up your server and loads browserSync.

Adding the following task should get things working for you.

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series( gulp.parallel('styles','fonts'), 'serve-php' ));
```

Just run `gulp`, the assets will be compiled first, then the server will start.

(If you already have a default task, you will need to change the name of this task)

I imagine you will also need to add your `js` task as a parameter inside the `parallel` function call but it’s difficult to tell without seeing the rest of your code.

I hope that gets you moving on the right path!

Comment: I added your task and this is far better but for example my dropdown buttons are not working. What is weird is that all the bootstrap buttons and syntax are working but not the dropdowns. Also I added my js task and some of my js is working but not the jquery.

Comment: I’m glad that got you part of the way! If you could provide your full gulp file or link to it, it would be much easier to tell, without it, any other suggestions would just be a stab in the dark!

Comment: @CamilleBOUQUET (stab in the dark here…) It sounds like jQuery is failing to load, it would be worth checking your console and see where it is loading from, are you using a cdn of jquery? is it’s path being rewritten when it shouldn’t?